# Canonical Vitali set

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The axiom of choice implies that there is a subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$ that are Vitali sets : this means that  $E$ is a transversal with respect to the additive subgroup $\mathbb Q$ of $\mathbb R$, i.e. the natural projection $p:{\mathbb R} \to \frac{{\mathbb R}}{\mathbb Q}$ becomes bijective when restricted to $E$.

It is also known that there are models of ZF where no Vitali sets exists.

My question is in-between : is there a formula $\phi$ of set theory such that it is provable in ZF that “If there is a Vitali set then $\phi$ defines a unique Vitali set”.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "no such $E$ exists". Do you also require that $E$ is uncountable? $E=\{\sqrt p\mid p$ prime$\}$ is an example of an infinite set, no two of its elements a rational distance apart. Perhaps the requirement is that $p\upharpoonright E$ is again onto?

Comment: @Andrés: I think that it’s clear that Ewan has in mind that $E$ should be a transversal for the family of cosets, and that *bijective* is intended to be *bijective with* $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed, that’s exactly what I meant.

Comment: Ewan, you seem to require that $E$ is some canonical Vitali set. I don't think this is possible, even if you do have the axiom of choice. One of the things that make Vitali sets so... "non-constructive" is exactly their non-canonical nature.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In your opinion, is it impossible to construct a “canonical example” for anything that needs the axiom of choice ?

Comment: Ewan, generally yes, unless that object is very very special. Vitali sets are not that special.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you know an example of such a “very very special” object ?

Comment: Ewan, look at the "canonical structure" papers by Cummings, Foreman and Magidor for several examples.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81082/unique-existence-and-the-axiom-of-choice might have some examples. Another would be, for example, minimal isomorphism type of a well-ordering of a set. If there is such ordering, then there is a minimal isomorphism type, but you need the axiom of choice to prove that such ordering exists at all.

Comment: It seems that the key property for such $\phi$ to exists (on any type of collection) is that $\sf ZF$ should be able to define some partial order structure on the collection of objects satisfying $\psi$, which has some definable element (which will be $E$, of course). Sometimes it's possible, other times it's not. I have my doubts about Vitali sets having this sort of canonical structure on them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you told me your opinion about the answer to this question, do you have one on the difficulty of proof ? My feeling is that the question is too hard to expect a full answer here on MSE, unless some expert already solved it in a paper.

Comment: I don't know how difficult a proof might be, somewhere between trivial and very nontrivial I suppose... You can flag this for a moderator attention and request this to be migrated to MathOverflow if you think it's a better place for the question.

Comment: As Andreas Blass points out in the comments to my answer, you probably want (4) $\exists E\,\phi(E)$.  Or instead of (1)-(4), you could say "if there is a Vitali set then $\phi$ defines a Vitali set" and not worry about what $\phi$ does in the case that there is no Vitali set.

Answer (score 6):

No, there cannot be a formula that always defines a Vitali set whenever one exists.  In fact we can say something stronger: There is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with no definable Vitali set.

Assume that $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC}$ holds but there is no Vitali set (this follows, for example, from "$\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC} + {}$every set of reals has the Baire property," which is consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by a theorem of Shelah.)  Force with $\text{Col}(\omega_1,\mathbb{R})$ to add a well-ordering of the reals.  Because the forcing is countably closed and $\mathsf{DC}$ holds in the ground model, no reals are added.  The generic extension has a well-ordering of its reals, so it has a Vitali set.  But it cannot have a definable Vitali set because the forcing is homogeneous, so every subset of the ground model that is definable in the forcing extension is an element of the ground model.

*Remark:* As Andreas Blass points out in the comments, there is a more direct construction assuming the existence of an inaccessible cardinal.
  Let $\kappa$ be inaccessible and let $g \subset \text{Col}(\omega,\mathord{<}\kappa)$ be a $V$-generic filter.
Then in the generic extension $V[g]$ every definable set of reals is Lebesgue measurable by a theorem of Solovay (in fact, every set of reals that is ordinal-definable from a real parameter is Lebesgue measurable, has the Baire property, *etc.*)  So in this generic extension there can be no definable Vitali set.

Comment: Very nice trick!

Comment: @Asaf Thanks.$\,\,$

Comment: You can also use Shelah's theorem about $\sf ZF+DC+BP$ rather than $\sf DC_{\omega_1}$. When it comes to adding reals, countable closure and $\sf DC$ are more than enough.

Comment: @Asaf Oops, I'm not familiar with the terminology and so I was thinking that $\mathsf{DC}_{\omega_1}$ was a weakening of $\mathsf{DC}$ rather than a strengthening.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: That sounds strange... weakening. I suppose I'm just so deep into that stuff it seems weird how someone can make this sort of mistake... :-) What would you say if I'd think that $\Sigma^2_1$ was actually second order? :-P

Comment: @Asaf Well, I do mistype $\Sigma^2_1$ as $\Sigma^1_2$ quite often :-)  Anyway I think the reason for my mistake is that $\mathsf{DC}_\mathbb{R}$ is a weakening of $\mathsf{DC}$.  The terminology is not consistent.

Comment: This construction via the Solovay model seems to be three steps, of which the last two are unnecessary. The steps are (1) Lévy-collapse all ordinals below an inaccessible $\kappa$ to be countable (so $\kappa$ becomes $\aleph_1$), (2) pass to an inner model like HOD$(\mathbb R)$, and (3) force to add a well-ordering of the reals. After step (1), you already have a model of ZFC where all HOD$(\mathbb R)$ sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable, so there's no Vitali set.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That is a good point. Thanks.  I wrote it this way because I was thinking of starting with the assumption $V = L(\mathbb{R}) + \mathsf{AD}$, and only tried to reduce the consistency strength as an afterthought.

Comment: By the way, the question was surely intended to have a fourth assertion deducible in ZF, namely $(\exists E)\,\phi(E)$.  As originally formulated, the question could be answered affirmatively (and stupidly) by taking $\phi$ to be $0=1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Heh, you're right.  I will mention this to the OP.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Thank you very much for your answer, I’ll need to learn a little more set theory to fully understand it. Do you happen to know a reference for Shelah’s theorem of existence of a model of ZF+DC+every set of reals has the Baire property ?

Comment: Trevor, the same point as Andreas made about Solovay's model can be made about Shelah's model as well. @Ewan: Shelah has a very difficult paper called "Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?"

Comment: By the way, Trevor, $\sf DC_\Bbb R$ should be written as $\sf DC(\Bbb R)$ instead. Besides, think about it, why would we need $\sf DC$ for sets of size $\aleph_1$? That much is provable from $\sf ZF$. And from that follows that $\sf DC(\omega_1)$ holds but it is consistent that there are countably closed forcings which add real numbers.

Comment: @Asaf Regarding Shelah's model, I suspected that the same remak might apply but I wasn't sure because I don't know the first thing about Shelah's proof.  As for $\mathsf{DC}_{\mathbb{R}}$ versus $\mathsf{DC}(\mathbb{R})$, the former notation is the one used in the $\mathsf{AD}$ context as far as I've seen.  And of course you are right that $\mathsf{DC}$ for sets of size $\omega_1$ is automatic, so that's not what I was thinking of either.  Who knows what I was thinking? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something much weaker is false: It is consistent with $ZFC$ that every (ordinal) definable collection of sets of reals consists solely of Lebesgue measurable sets of reals or has the same size as the set of all subsets of continuum. This (and a category analogue of it) is due to Harvey Friedman.

Comment: I am not sure if you'd care about it but a determinacy analogue of this also holds using a very similar forcing - I learned this from Woodin.