# Why can't we construct a Vitali Set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We have an existence proof, but why is it hard to construct a concrete example of one?

Comment: Because its existence is dependent on the Axiom Choice. There are set theories in which the Axiom of Choice is false, and Vitali sets do not exist: every subset of the real line is measurable. So its existence is intimately tied with the Axiom of Choice, which implies its existence is not going to be “concrete”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks! so if we assume AoC, then why can't we construct a concrete example?

Comment: What does “concrete” mean? If it means doing it in some way that does not invoke the Axiom of Choice, it’s because you **need** the Axiom of Choice to prove its existence.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "concrete" means a specific case of a vitali set, some subset of the real line, which satisfies the definition of a Vitali set. Just like $\sqrt{2}$ is a concrete example of an irrational number.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578268/canonical-vitali-set

Comment: You can’t give something which is both explicit and unique, as that would mean that you can construct such a set without invoking the Axiom of Choice, which is inherently impossible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see — how about just explicit?

Comment: Again, no: explicit means describing it exactly... which makes it unique.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah, ok — so these things only exist because we are assuming we can get the elements via AoC (part of proof).

Comment: Yes; the fact that there are set theories where a negation of the axiom of choice is assumed and where one can *prove* that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable tells you that there is something inherently non-constructive about nonmeasurable sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "concrete" you mean not invoking the Axiom of Choice, then as pointed out in the comment, this is impossible.

This suggests that the whole thing boils down to defining "concrete". I'd guess you want it to at least be *fixed*: the Axiom of Choice provides an *arbitrary* set satisfying the requirements, and thus the proof of the existence of Vitali sets does not pin down a unique set. However, if a unique Vitali set could be constructed, such a constructive process would not refer to the Axiom of Choice, since it is against the very nature of constructiveness(!). This is impossible.

There might be some other definitions of "concreteness", which may or may not lead to a "concrete Vitali set".

Comment: I understand now — AoC “gives” us such a set by definition — without AoC they wouldn’t exist.